# PyQt no button.clicked.connect function?

Tags: python, pyqt4

I've got PyQt4 with a python 3.4 and there is this strange bug occurring. Whenever I try to call btn.clicked.connect(), Pycharm will throw this error:

```
Cannot find reference "connect" in "function".
```

So for example:

```
btn = QtGui.QPushButton("Quit", self)
btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
```

will throw this error. How? Do I have missing files?

Comment: try:  self.button = QtGui.QPushButton('Quit', self) and self.btn.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)

Comment: Nope, already tried, but sadly not working

Comment: For sanity check - what's the `PyQt`'s version?

Comment: 4, Its funny because everything else is working.

Comment: A workaround might be `self.connect(btn, SIGNAL("clicked()"), the_slot)` if self derives from `QWidget`

Comment: Not working this way, but thank you for your time anyways!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Events and Signals in PyQt4 - PyQt4 Tutorial - ZetCode](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/):

> PyQt4.5 introduced a new style API for working with signals and
>   slots.
>
> ```
> QtCore.QObject.connect(button, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'),self.onClicked)
> ```
>
> This is the old style API.
>
> ```
> button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)
> ```
>
> The new style adheres more to the Python standards.

Comment: Eh, what "works" here? Python does execute this correctly, yes. But Pycharm and it's Python analysis does still not correctly handle `button.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)`. The warning persists, because it can not defer the type of `clicked`. Any hints here how to make this work?